# ME3 Import Save from ME2 Halfway through?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-2

Is it possible for me to import a Mass Effect 2 save into Mass Effect 3 if I have already done some missions without it?

I bought and played about 10 hours of Mass Effect 3 already and I really love the game. But a friend of mine gave me a Mass Effect 2 save file yesterday. Knowing that I miss out on a lot of content in Mass Effect 3 without a save file in Mass Effect 2, I want to import the save file.

Is there a way to do this without loosing 10 hours of my game play in Mass Effect 3?

Answer (score 2):

You can't import a ME2 save into an already started ME3 game. You will need to start over if you want to import.

If you're looking for a save with particular parameters (Wrex killed/convinced, Council abandoned/saved, etc), you should check out [masseffect2saves.com](http://www.masseffect2saves.com/).